# TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined for event.target in event listener

Tags: javascript, color-picker

So I have this code

I am trying to log the hex value to the console outside of the function.
when I put the console.log inside the function like so `console.log(updatedColor);` before the function closing it works.

the error I'm getting is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
    at updateFirst1 (script.js:15)
    at script.js:21
updateFirst1    @   script.js:15
(anonymous)
```

line 15 is `chosenColor.style.backgroundColor = event.target.value;` and line 21 is the console log.

```js
var colorSelect;

window.addEventListener("load", startup);

function startup() {
  colorSelect = document.querySelector("#color-picker");
  colorSelect.addEventListener("input", updateFirst1);
  colorSelect.select();
}

function updateFirst1(event) {
  var chosenColor = document.querySelector(".colored-box");

  if (chosenColor) {
    chosenColor.style.backgroundColor = event.target.value;
  }
  var updatedColor = event.target.value;
  return updatedColor;
}

console.log(updateFirst1());
```

```css
#colored-box {
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="colored-box" id="colored-box"></div>

  <label for="color-picker">Color:</label>
  <input type="color" value="#ff0000" id="color-picker">

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you call the function directly, rather than through an event listener, there's no event, so no `event.target`.

Comment: Also, `event` should be the function parameter, not a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are calling your `updateFirst` function manually outside of your event, so the `event` object is undefined and you are getting an error. When the `console.log()` is inside of the function, the `event` is defined as it is called from the input listener you added in your `startup` function.

Comment: Then how can i use the hex value im getting from this function outside of it?

Comment: That depends, what are you trying to achieve with the value outside of the event?

Comment: a string i can store in a var will do

Comment: The simple answer is that you can have a global variable by setting `window.updatedColour = updatedColour` within your event - but note that if you use this value it won't be "reactive" - meaning that if, for example, you set the `innerText` of a DOM element to the value of that variable, it wouldn't update it on event. If this is what you had in mind, I highly recommend taking a look at [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Getting-Started)

Comment: To clarify: you'd only be able to read the updated value of `window.updatedColour` if the code that references it is called after the event occurs

Answer (score 0):

you need to use log the result just when color is picking so just use `console.log` inside the function `updateFirst1`

**Code:**

```js
var colorSelect;

window.addEventListener("load", startup);

function startup() {
  colorSelect = document.querySelector("#color-picker");
  colorSelect.addEventListener("input", updateFirst1);
  colorSelect.select();
}

function updateFirst1(event) {
  var chosenColor = document.querySelector(".colored-box");

  if (chosenColor) {
    chosenColor.style.backgroundColor = event.target.value;
  }
  var updatedColor = event.target.value; 
  
  console.log(updatedColor);
}
```

```css
#colored-box {
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="colored-box" id="colored-box"></div>

  <label for="color-picker">Color:</label>
  <input type="color" value="#ff0000" id="color-picker">

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: but i am trying to get this value out of the function